# Using the BigQuery Connector with Spark

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm not getting the Google example work

[https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example%20PySpark)
PySpark

There are a few mistakes in the code i think, like:

'# Output Parameters
    'mapred.bq.project.id': '',

Should be: 'mapred.bq.output.project.id': '',

and

'# Write data back into new BigQuery table.
'# BigQueryOutputFormat discards keys, so set key to None.
(word_counts
 .map(lambda pair: None, json.dumps(pair))
 .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf))

will give an error message. If I change it to:
(word_counts
 .map(lambda pair: (None, json.dumps(pair)))
 .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf))

I get the error message:
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

And whatever I try I can not make this work. 
There is a dataset created in BigQuery with the name I gave it in the 'conf' with a trailing '_hadoop_temporary_job_201512081419_0008' 
And a table is created with '_attempt_201512081419_0008_r_000000_0' on the end. But are always empty

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We are working to update [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example%20PySpark) because, as you noted, the docs are incorrect in this case. Sorry about that! While we're working to update the docs, I wanted to get you a reply ASAP.

**Casting problem**

The most important problem you mention is the casting issue. Unfortunately,PySpark cannot use the `BigQueryOutputFormat` to create Java GSON objects. The solution (workaround) is to save the output data into [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) (GCS) and then load it manually with the `bq` command.

**Code example**

Here is a code sample which exports to GCS and loads the data into BigQuery. You could also use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and Python to execute the `bq` command programatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""BigQuery I/O PySpark example."""
import json
import pprint
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

# Use the Google Cloud Storage bucket for temporary BigQuery export data used
# by the InputFormat. This assumes the Google Cloud Storage connector for
# Hadoop is configured.
bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory ='gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
    # Input Parameters
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'publicdata',
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'samples',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'shakespeare',
}

# Load data in from BigQuery.
table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)

# Perform word count.
word_counts = (
    table_data
    .map(lambda (_, record): json.loads(record))
    .map(lambda x: (x['word'].lower(), int(x['word_count'])))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y))

# Display 10 results.
pprint.pprint(word_counts.take(10))

# Stage data formatted as newline delimited json in Google Cloud Storage.
output_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output'.format(bucket)
partitions = range(word_counts.getNumPartitions())
output_files = [output_directory + '/part-{:05}'.format(i) for i in partitions]

(word_counts
 .map(lambda (w, c): json.dumps({'word': w, 'word_count': c}))
 .saveAsTextFile(output_directory))

# Manually clean up the input_directory, otherwise there will be BigQuery export
# files left over indefinitely.
input_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(input_directory)
input_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(input_path, True)

print """
###########################################################################
# Finish uploading data to BigQuery using a client e.g.
bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    --schema 'word:STRING,word_count:INTEGER' \
    wordcount_dataset.wordcount_table {files}
# Clean up the output
gsutil -m rm -r {output_directory}
###########################################################################
""".format(
    files=','.join(output_files),
    output_directory=output_directory)
```